# Java Applet using local scanner not working and no errors

Tags: java, eclipse, applet, native-code

I am a newbie in Java but I need to make a scanner (that has a built in ocr) output some content to a browser. I haven't gotten to the browser yet, but the code works when I run it as an application.
With the scanner, I received Java code that makes the scanner take a picture, then read from it and output it back to the console. I added a few lines to make it an applet:

```
import gx.*;
import pr.*;
import java.applet.*;

public class DocScan extends Applet
{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    static
    {
        try
        {
            System.loadLibrary("jgx");
            System.loadLibrary("jpr");
        }
        catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e)
        {
            System.err.println("Native code library failed to load." + e);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String argv[])
    {
        Lib lib = new Lib();
        String text;
        String[] ec ={ "Ok", "Warning", "Error" };

        try
        {
            /* Opening the PR system */
            lib.FunctionStart("Opening system files");
            PassportReader pr = new PassportReader();   /* Object for the PR system */
            lib.FunctionEnd();

            /* Validity check */
            if (!pr.IsValid())
            {
                lib.Error("Failed to initialize!");
                lib.PrintStat();
            }

            /* Connecting to the first device */
            lib.FunctionStart("Connecting to the first device");
            pr.UseDevice(0, jpr.PR_UMODE_FULL_CONTROL);
            lib.FunctionEnd();

            /* Using the device */
            while (!lib.KbHit())
            {
                lib.ProcessStart("Processing document");

                try
                {
                    /* Capturing images */
                    lib.FunctionStart("Capturing images");
                    pr.Capture();
                    lib.FunctionEnd();

                    /* Getting document data */
                    lib.FunctionStart("Recognizing.");
                    prDoc doc = pr.Recognize(0);
                    lib.FunctionEnd();

                    if (!doc.IsValid()) lib.WriteLine("No data found.");
                    else
                    {
                        /* Displaying document type */
                        lib.WriteLine("Document type: " + doc.Code() + ", status: " + ec[doc.Status() / 100]);

                        /* Get some fixed fields and displaying them */
                        text = doc.Field(jpr.PR_DF_NAME);
                        if (!text.equals("")) lib.WriteLine("NAME \"" + text + "\" [" + ec[doc.FieldStatus(jpr.PR_DF_NAME) / 100] + "]");

                        text = doc.Field(jpr.PR_DF_DOCUMENT_NUMBER);
                        if (!text.equals("")) lib.WriteLine("DOCUMENT NUMBER \"" + text + "\" [" + ec[doc.FieldStatus(jpr.PR_DF_DOCUMENT_NUMBER) / 100] + "]");

                        text = doc.Field(jpr.PR_DF_EXPIRY_DATE);
                        if (!text.equals("")) lib.WriteLine("EXPIRY DATE \"" + text + "\" [" + ec[doc.FieldStatus(jpr.PR_DF_EXPIRY_DATE) / 100] + "]");

                        /* Searching for fields and displaying them */
                        gxVariant pdoc = doc.ToVariant();
                        gxVariant fieldlist = new gxVariant();
                        pdoc.GetChild(fieldlist, jgx.GX_VARIANT_BY_ID, jpr.PRV_FIELDLIST, 0);
                        int nitems = fieldlist.GetNItems();
                        for (int i = 0; i < nitems; i++)
                        {
                            gxVariant field = new gxVariant();
                            fieldlist.GetItem(field, jgx.GX_VARIANT_BY_INDEX, 0, i);
                            int field_code = field.GetInt();
                            text = doc.Field(field_code);
                            if (!text.equals("")) lib.WriteLine("[" + field_code + "] \"" + text + "\" [" + ec[doc.FieldStatus(field_code) / 100] + "]");

                            if (field_code >= jpr.PR_DF_FORMATTED) continue;
                            try
                            {
                                gxImage img = doc.FieldImage(field_code);
                                if (img.IsValid()) img.Save(field_code + ".jpg", jgx.GX_JPEG);
                            }
                            catch (RuntimeException e)
                            {
                                lib.DisplExcp(e);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (RuntimeException e)
                {
                    lib.DisplExcp(e);
                }

                lib.ProcessEnd();
                lib.WaitForSec(3);
            }

            /* Closing the device */
            lib.FunctionStart("Closing the device");
            pr.CloseDevice();
            lib.FunctionEnd();

        }
        catch (RuntimeException e)
        {
            lib.DisplExcp(e);
        }

        lib.PrintStat();
    }
}
```

I am using Eclipse as an IDE. Right now my goal is to simply make the scanner "flash". I know that the output is to the console and I will not see anything from it in an applet, but it should still flash.

When I run this code as an application, it works. The scanner takes a picture and then it outputs what it has read to the console.

When I run this code as an Applet, the applet starts and does nothing. It just stays there with no errors of any kind (at least that's what Eclipse is showing me).

I read that I should allow the applet accesss, so I edited:

```
c:\program files\java\jre8\lib\security\java.policy
```

and added this at the end:

```
grant {
        permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

Which should allow applets full access. However, there is no change - the applet still launches and does nothing.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Why is the code not working when I run it as an applet?

Comment: What is `lib.DisplExcp(e);`?  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: Ensure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show for applets & JWS apps.  If there is no output at the default level, raise it and try again.

Comment: *"edited: ..`java.policy`"*  No applet in this day and age will make it to the screen of a typical end user unless it is digitally signed with a certificate issued by a Certification Authority.  Might as well get one now and save the bother of editing policy files.

Comment: @DreamWave How did you fix this problem? thanks.